# Python Pandas - Dataframe - Add column depending on another column, which has a mathematical operation from another two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

| timestamp | Place | Data A | Data B | Data C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16508 | France | 0.03 | 0.06 | 0.15 |
| 16510 | England | 0.05 | 0.07 | 0.11 |
| 16515 | England | 0.04 | 0.03 | 0.87 |

What I would like to do is the following:

- Add a new column for every different value in the column "Place".
- In this new column, add the division between Data A and Data B in percentage (Data A / Data B * 100).

The expected output would be:

| timestamp | Place | Data A | Data B | Data C | To France | To England |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16508 | France | 0.03 | 0.06 | 0.15 | 50 | 0 |
| 16510 | England | 0.05 | 0.07 | 0.11 | 0 | 71.42 |
| 16515 | England | 0.04 | 0.03 | 0.87 | 0 | 133.33 |

I tried the following:

```
for column in data['Place'].unique():
    column_name = f'To {Place}'
    data[column_name] = data[data['Place'] == column]['Data A'].div(['Data B'])*100
    data[column_name].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
    data[column_name].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
```

But it's not working. I get a "'list' object has no attribute 'div'" error. I have tried other different things but they are not working either.

Could somebody give me a hand with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try with `pivot`:

```
df["Ratio"] = df["Data A"].div(df["Data B"])

output = df.drop("Ratio", axis=1).join(df.pivot(None, "Place", "Ratio").mul(100).fillna(0).add_prefix("To "))

>>> output
     Place  Data A  Data B  Data C  To England  To France
0   France    0.03    0.06    0.15    0.000000       50.0
1  England    0.05    0.07    0.11   71.428571        0.0
2  England    0.04    0.03    0.87  133.333333        0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
df_ratio = ((df['Data A'].div(df['Data B'])*100).to_frame()
               .assign(col='To '+df['Place'])
               .set_index('col', append=True)[0]
               .unstack(fill_value=0))

pd.concat([df, df_ratio], axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   timestamp    Place  Data A  Data B  Data C  To England  To France
0      16508   France    0.03    0.06    0.15    0.000000       50.0
1      16510  England    0.05    0.07    0.11   71.428571        0.0
2      16515  England    0.04    0.03    0.87  133.333333        0.0
```